# Copying/over-writing one source to another in TFS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

**Question Background:**

Within my TF Server I have two folders, one is a simple 'HelloWorld.sln' in a folder called 'HelloWorldDev' and the other is a 'HelloWorld.sln' in a folder called 'HelloWorldQA'. Each folder contains its respective .cs files etc.

I want to checkout a file from the HelloWorld QA folder, replace - or update it - with a version from the HelloWorldDev folder with the same file name, then check this file back into the HelloWorldQA folder with the relevant changes.

**Question:**

I am very new to the TFS API so I'm not 100% if what I'm trying to ask is the correct way to proceed, or if its even possible. Can someone give me an example of achieving this?

**Code so far:**

```
       string fileName = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\TfsServer\HelloWorldQA\IHelloWorld.cs";
        string fileNameQA = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\TfsServer\HelloWorld\IHelloWorld.cs";

        string uri = @"https://tfsServer.visualstudio.com/";

        var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(fileName);
        var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
        var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);

        workspace.PendEdit(fileName);


        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);


        var workspaceInfoQA = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(fileNameQA);
        var serverQA = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
        var workspaceQA = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(serverQA);

        workspace.PendEdit(fileNameQA);


        FileInfo fiQA = new FileInfo(fileNameQA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of using 2 workspaces, you can simply map both folders in the same workspace.

Then you're looking for a [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.merge.aspx) operation:

```
        var sourcePath = workspace.GetServerItemForLocalItem(fileName);
        var targetPath = workspace.GetServerItemForLocalItem(fileNameQA);

        var getStatus = workspace.Merge(sourcePath, targetPath, null, null);
        if (getStatus.NumUpdated > 0)
        {
            //OK
        }
```